# What did i miss out in my AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, database

I would like to delete a picture using ajax, but im not sure where when wrong with my buttons.

this is my First page with the pictures.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">               </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#button").click(removecat);
            });

            function removecat() {
                $("#resultDIV").load("removecat.php");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">

    <?php
    require 'dbfunction.php';
    require 'DBCategory.php';

    $con = getDbConnect();
    $categoryArr = getcategoryArrCon($con, "STATUS_ACTIVE");


    foreach ($categoryArr as $Name => $InfoArr) {
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="title">
       <h3><?php echo $Name; ?></h3>
    </div>
    <img src="<?php echo "img/" . $InfoArr['image'] ?>" class="img-rounded" width="250" height="220">
    <a class="btn btn-danger"  id="button" value="Delete" name="delete">Delete</a>
    <br /><br />
    <div id="resultDIV">
    </div>
    </div>               
    <?php } ?>
    </div>

    </body>
```

This is my removecat.php page,

```html
<?php
  require 'dbfunction.php';
  $con = getDbConnect();

  if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } else {
     mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE category SET status = 1 WHERE categoryid = '$Name'"); //$name from Firstpage

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($con) > 0) {
        echo "You have successfully remove $Name."; //$name from Firstpage
    } else {
        echo "NO changes were made.";
    }
  mysqli_close($con);
  }
 ?>
```

I am not very sure about how to channel the $name from first page to the removecat.php page. Can someone help?

Comment: Use $.ajax not $.load

Comment: My buttons did not work

Comment: how can they work ? you are missing key points, 1. make sure each button will have different id 2. and pass some var to remove page so it can verify which image should delete

Comment: just use/append a value on `.load`, like `?name=concatenate here`. then use a `$_GET['name']` on the PHP